# simple html dom not found img tag on server

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/  ver 1.5

This script work under windows 7, do not work under linux

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$sUrl = 'http://baby.ru/';
$oParser = str_get_html(file_get_contents($sUrl));

// this work everywhere
foreach($oParser->find('title') as $oElement) {
    echo $oElement->plaintext."\n";
}

// this work only under windows 7, not work on server under linux
foreach($oParser->find('img') as $oElement) {
    echo $oElement->src."\n";
}
```

Windows output (title + img)

- бэби.ру: беременность, календарь беременности, беременность по
  неделям
- http://www.tns-counter.ru/V13a****baby_ru/ru/CP1251/tmsec=baby_total/
- http://www.baby.ru/pic/top_menu/logo2.png
- /i/partners/plantex/2013/pridanoe/kroxa.png
- /i/partners/pampers/assistants2.gif
- ...

Linux output (only title tag)

- бэби.ру: беременность, календарь беременности, беременность по неделям

PHP produce no error.

As you see "title" tag work everywhere. What happen with "img" tag?

What may be wrong on my server?

Comment: You are using file_get_contents(), but you have not specified a file?

Comment: file_get_contents() can load html from url (depend on php settings)

Comment: It works for me on ubuntu